# Use initrd as principal file system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, debian, initrd

My Initrd contains all tools that I need, Is it possible to use it as the principal file system?
Which variables must be specified to the kernel ?
I tried with root=/dev/ram0, but it did not work .

Comment: Change the scripts in the initrd to *not* mount another root.

Comment: ... and/or, if you know which program from your `initrd` you like to run after boot, just give the kernel an `init=/path-within-initrd/to/my-program-of-choice` argument. It'll automatically start that (in place of `init` / as PID 1) for you.